# Pass Apollo Persisted Queries hash to backend services

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, graphql-java

With a given setup:

```
frontend client <n ----- 1> Apollo Gateway <1 ----- n> backend services
```

is there a way to use Apollo Persisted Queries (APQ) from a backend server's side perspective?

According to https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/apq/ the hash and the associated queries are stored on Apollo Server. On hit the query is executed on Apollo Server side.

There are java libraries which implemented support for APQ, e.g. https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/pull/2013.

Is there an option to build the hash of the (sub)graph and pass it to the servers? Is there something I fundementally misunderstood?